# KafkaConsumer connects to the wrong broker, and therefore cannot consume

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I've written a small script based on an example in the Kafka documentation:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

import collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.Properties

object ConsumerDemo extends App {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getSimpleName)

  def consumerFromKafka() = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", broker_address)
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
    props.put("group.id", "consumer-group")
    logger.info(s"Properties: ${props}")
    val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String] = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
    val topics: List[String]                    = topic :: Nil
    consumer.subscribe(topics.asJava)
    while (true) {
      val record = consumer.poll(1000).asScala
      for (data <- record.iterator)
        println(data.value())
    }
  }

  consumerFromKafka()

}
```

When I run the script I get the following output:

```
110    INFO  ConsumerDemo$ {35} - Properties: {key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer, value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer, group.id=consumer-group, bootstrap.servers=172.16.146.89:9092, auto.offset.reset=latest} 
302    INFO  ConsumerDemo$ {35} - Subscribing to topics List(Greetings) 
2507   WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient {35} - [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-group-1, groupId=consumer-group] Connection to node 2147483646 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. 
4656   WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient {35} - [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-group-1, groupId=consumer-group] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

The first line confirms the properties that are being used to initialize this Consumer.

I'm not running Kafka locally, I am running on a nearby server (172.16.146.89:9092).

It looks like I've given it a valid input for **bootstrap.servers**, but that value seems to be ignored. It's trying to connect to a broker on localhost which does not exist.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the broker configuration. Specifically, there is a property [advertised.listeners](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_advertised.listeners), that I suspect is set localhost.